# error while loading images in recyclerView using glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have a fragment called "RecyclerTab1" which holds the recyclerview layout."HomeManager" is the recyclerview adapter.Within that recyclerview adapterI have used Glide to load images from drawable folder.Whe I try to run the program I get the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:`.I have also included the RecyclerTab1 class and the HomeManager adapter for recyclerview

RecyclerTab1:

```
package com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.hometabfragments;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.HomeRecyclerDetailActivity;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.R;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.projectdatabase.HomeManager;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.projectdatabase.HomeData;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.projectdatabase.RecyclerClickListener;
import com.kogitune.activity_transition.ActivityTransitionLauncher;

public class RecyclerTab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_tab1_recycler, container, false);
        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.home_recyclerview);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.smoothScrollToPosition(View.SCROLLBAR_POSITION_DEFAULT);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true); // to improve performance
        rv.setAdapter(new HomeManager(getContext())); // the projectdatabase manager is assigner to the RV

        rv.addOnItemTouchListener( // and the click is handled
                new RecyclerClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeRecyclerDetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(HomeRecyclerDetailActivity.ID, HomeData.PROJECTS[position].getId());
                        ActivityTransitionLauncher.with(getActivity()).from(view).launch(intent);
                    }
                }));
        return v;
    }
}
```

HomeManager:

```
package com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.projectdatabase;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.R;


public class HomeManager extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeManager.RecyclerViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
public HomeManager(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}
    public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView mProjectName, mProjectCity, mProjectType;
        ImageView mImage;
        CheckBox mCheck;
        RelativeLayout mProjectStatus;


        RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mProjectName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_name);
            mProjectCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_city);
            mProjectType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_type);
            mImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_image);
            mCheck = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_fav);
            mProjectStatus = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        // get the single element from the main array

        final HomeData projects = HomeData.PROJECTS[i];
        // Set the values
        viewHolder.mProjectName.setText(projects.get(HomeData.Field.NAME));
        viewHolder.mProjectCity.setText(projects.get(HomeData.Field.CITY));
        viewHolder.mProjectType.setText(projects.get(HomeData.Field.TYPE));
        viewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(projects.geti(HomeData.Field.IMAGE));
        viewHolder.mCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "Item Favorited", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        });

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(Gallery_Constants.IMAGES)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .into(viewHolder.mImage);
        if (projects.get(HomeData.Field.STATUS) == "FOR SALE") {
            viewHolder.mProjectStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.labelsale);
        } else if (projects.get(HomeData.Field.STATUS) == "SOLD OUT") {
            viewHolder.mProjectStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.labelsold);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return HomeData.PROJECTS.length;
    }


}
```

Logcat:

```
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors, PID: 8509
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown type class [Ljava.lang.String;. You must provide a Model of a type for which there is a registered ModelLoader, if you are using a custom model, you must first call Glide#register with a ModelLoaderFactory for your custom model class
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.loadGeneric(RequestManager.java:629)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.load(RequestManager.java:598)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.projectdatabase.HomeManager.onBindViewHolder(HomeManager.java:68)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.projectdatabase.HomeManager.onBindViewHolder(HomeManager.java:19)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5212)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5245)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4483)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4359)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5107)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5107)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5107)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1627)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5107)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5107)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1133)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5107)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5107)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5107)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5107)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
12-01 12:30:17.368 8509-8509/com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.view.View.layout(View
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glide provides so many .with() methods for a reason: it follows lifecycle.

Imagine a Fragment that is dynamically added to an Activity. In its onCreateView method it starts a Glide load of a 3MB image. Now, what if the user presses the back button and the Fragment is removed or the whole activity is closed?

1. If you use with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()) nothing will
   happen, all 3MBs of data is downloaded and then decoded, cached,
   probably even set to the ImageView, which is then garbage collected,
   because the only reference to it was from Glide internals.
2. If you use with((Fragment)this) Glide subscribes to the Fragment's
   lifecycle events and as soon as the Fragment is stopped, the any
   outstanding request should be paused; and when destroyed, all
   pending requests be cleared. This means that the image download will
   stop midway and no more resources will be used by that dead
   Fragment.
3. If you use with(getActivity()) Glide subscribes to the Activity's
   lifecycle events and the same thing happens as above, but only when
   the Activity is stopped or destroyed. So the best practice is to use
   the closest possible context/fragment to avoid unused request
   completions.

Hope this helps you..

Answer (score 1):

you get the ERROR like this :

```
IllegalArgumentException: Unknown type class [Ljava.lang.String;
```

it probably provides a String[] to the Glide.load().

please check here:

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(Gallery_Constants.IMAGES)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(viewHolder.mImage);
```

make sure the type of the Gallery_Constants.IMAGES is correct.